# Recovering surface normal vectors from RGB normal map?

Tags: normals, normal-map

I have an `uint16` RGB normal map from Blender and want to recover the normal vector at each pixel.

Based on [this page of the Blender manual](https://www.blender.org/manual/render/blender_render/textures/properties/influence/bump_and_normal.html),

> Normal maps in Blender store a normal as follows:
>
> Red maps from (0 - 255) to X (-1.0 - 1.0)
>
> Green maps from (0 - 255) to Y (-1.0 - 1.0)
>
> Blue maps from (0 - 255) to Z (0.0 - 1.0)
>
> Since normals all point towards a viewer, negative Z-values are not
>   stored (they would be invisible anyway).

I tried

```
x = 2*r/65535-1
y = 2*g/65535-1
z = b/65535,
```

but the results don't look right.

Comment: Why 65535? why not 255?

Comment: @batFINGER Under my current settings, the output normal maps are `uint16`, so every pixel ranges from 0 to 65535 (2^16) rather than 255 (2^8).

Comment: Ok then you want to convert uint16 to uint8.  Using 65535 assumes a linear relationship whereas its 256 * 256

Comment: eg use  r = uint16val // 256

Comment: Sorry, not sure if I get you. Are you suggesting I should do `x = 2*(r/256)/256-1`? Isn't this what I did?